# How to hide a text label displaying over color swatch field?

Tags: css

I'm having this weird glitch where on certain browsers, a text label is appearing over my color swatch (displaying the name of it). [Here's a screen recording](https://streamable.com/xd8tc) to check it out. It's pretty easy to understand what's wrong after seeing what happens. Confused on why it's displaying a label over the color swatch. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code I'm using to display the color swatches.

```
$colors: ( 
 'color-Dark\ Grey\ Heather'     #3E3C3D, 
 'color-Heather\ Deep\ Teal'     #426275,
 'color-Heather\ True\ Royal'    #5F98E6,
);

@each $color in $colors {
 $colorName: nth($color, 1);
 $bgColor:   nth($color, 2);

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName} + label {
 background-color: $bgColor;
 color: $bgColor;
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 25px;
 margin: 5px;
 text-indent: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;

@if $colorName == Dark\ Grey\ Heather' or $colorName == 'color- 
  Heather\ Deep\ Teal' or $colorName == 'color-Heather\ True\ Royal {
  background-image: url(my-heather-swatch-goes-here.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 35px 35px;
}
 }

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName}:checked + label {
 border-color: #555;
 border-width: 3px;
}
 }
```

Comment: Is your problem the highlight?

Comment: yeah, I don't want the single letter text that's appearing over the color swatches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with text-indent, it should hide the text, try change text-indent from 100% to -2000px for example.

```
 text-indent: -2000px;
```

also make sure your element/label is not inline, and if you can share live url of this page, we can check it and give more accurate answer.

Comment: So awesome. Cannot describe how much I appreciate it. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Levi you are mostly welcome, please check the answer as solution when you have time.

Comment: Just did! Would you mind looking at my most recent question? Not a big deal if you can't solve it, just wondering since no-one has yet to answer. Thanks again!